# trying to install lync 2010 and experiecing an error with central management store

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, active-directory, lync

I'm trying to install Lync 2010 and i'm getting stuck in the stage where i have to install or point to the local configuration store.
I've tried finding it in the domain and without luck, any recommendations?

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator.ASUTA> Get-csconfigurationstorelocation
WARNING: No Configuration Store location has been set.
PS C:\Users\Administrator.ASUTA> Get-CsComputer "$env:computername.$env:userdnsd
omain"
Get-CsComputer : Cannot find location of Central Management Store in Active Dir
ectory.
At line:1 char:15
+ Get-CsComputer <<<<  "$env:computername.$env:userdnsdomain"
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [Get-CsComputer], Manag
   ementStoreNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ManagementStoreNotFound,Microsoft.Rtc.Management
   .Xds.GetComputerCmdlet
PS C:\Users\Administrator.ASUTA>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before installing Lync Server, did you extend the Active Directory schema and configure the required objects (per http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398630.aspx)?